# The type and definition of a function that is formed from two given functions

Tags: haskell

I was asked to write the most simple definition of the result of `s k k`, where

```
s = \ f g x -> f x (g x)
s :: (t1 -> t2 -> t3) -> (t1 -> t2) -> t1 -> t3
k = \ x y -> x
k :: p1 -> p2 -> p1
```

Writing `:t s k k` in the terminal gives: `t -> t`.

I think `s` takes two functions - `f` and `g`. where `f` takes `t1` and `t2` as inputs and returns `t3`. function `g` takes `t1` as input and returns `t2`, and `x` is `t1`. Why is `t3` the return type?

I think I understand function `k`, where you take `x` and `y` as inputs and the type of `x` is output. Is there a common approach when it comes to understanding how these two functions will work  together forming `s k k`.

I also tried going step by step typing `:t s k`, which gives `(t3 -> t2) -> t3 -> t3`, however, that didn't help me too much :) Can someone explain this to someone new to Haskell?

Comment: You can make use of *beta-reductions* to reduce the expression until no further *beta-reductions* are possible.

Comment: Ignore the types for now and just substitute f and g with k (or \ x y -> x) where x is still unknown and you will get a function that takes a value of type t and returns a value of type t

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If `fun :: a1 -> b` and `arg :: a2`, then the application `fun arg :: b` and `a1 ~ a2` (`a1` is equal to `a2`).

`s k k` is the same as `(s k) k` because function application associates to the left. So we have an application `s k`:

```
s   :: (t1 -> t2 -> t3) -> (t1 -> t2) -> t1 -> t3
k   :: (p1 -> p2 -> p1)

s k ::                     (t1 -> t2) -> t1 -> t3

p1 ~ t1
p2 ~ t2
p1 ~ t3
```

Note that `p1 ~ t1` and `p1 ~ t3`, therefore `t1 ~ t3`:

```
s k ::                     (t1 -> t2) -> t1 -> t1
```

In the application `(s k) k`, a similar thing happens; I’ll rename the type variables with a prime `'` to indicate that this is a different instantiation of `k`’s type:

```
(s k)   :: (t1  -> t2        ) -> t1 -> t1
      k :: (p1' -> p2' -> p1')

(s k) k ::                        t1 -> t1

t1 ~ p1'
t2 ~ p2' -> p1'
```

Notice that when `t1 -> t2` is unified with `p1' -> p2' -> p1'`, which is equal to `p1' -> (p2' -> p1')` because function types are right-associative, `t2` is equated with the function type `p2' -> p1'`.

As a result, the type of the whole expression is `t1 -> t1`, or `forall t1. t1 -> t1` with `ExplicitForAll`. Even without knowing the term here, there is only one function (which is total) of the type `forall a. a -> a`, and that is `id`. Indeed `s k k` is just a roundabout way of implementing the identity function, because for any `X` we give it, it returns `X`:

```
s k k X
(\ f g x -> f x (g x)) k k X
(\ g x -> k x (g x)) k X
(\ x -> k x (k x)) X
k X (k X)
(\ x y -> x) X (k X)
(\ y -> X) (k X)
X
```

The first `k` selects `X`, and the second application of `k` is ignored. That’s why neither of the type variables from the second use of `k` (`p1'` and `p2'`) appear in the resulting type.

Answer (score 2):

Well we know from their definitions that

```
s k k x = k x (k x) = x 

-- s = \f g x -> f x (g x)
-- s    k k x =  k x (k x)

-- k = \ x  y    -> x
-- k     x  y    =  x
-- k     x (k x) =  x
```

so that

```
s k k = \ x -> x
```

and thus its type is

```
a -> a
```

GHCi concurs (as you've already noted):

```
> :t s k k
s k k :: t3 -> t3
```

As to the types in `s` you ask about,

```
s :: (t1 -> t2 -> t3) -> (t1 -> t2) -> t1 -> t3
s = \ f g x -> f x (g x)
s     f g x =  f x (g x)
--
--         x  :: t1
--       g    :: t1 -> t2
--       g x  ::       t2
--    x       :: t1
--  f         :: t1 -> t2 -> t3
--  f x (g x) ::             t3
```

just follow from the most basic rule of type inference in application,

```
        x  ::  A                          x :: a
      f    ::  A -> B                   f   :: b -> c
    -------------------                --------------
      f x  ::       B                   f x ::      c  , a ~ b
```

This is analogous to Modus Ponens in logic, *"if we have A, and A implies B, then B holds as well"*.

---

If you wanted to get this from the *types* of `s` and `k` a.o.t. their definitions, a similar kind of diagram works for that as well:

```
s     :: (a -> b -> c) -> (a ->     b    ) -> a -> c
  k   ::  x -> y -> x
-------  a~x, b~y, c~x  => c~x~a  -------------------
s k   ::                  (a  ->    b    ) -> a -> a
    k ::                   x2 -> y2 -> x2
----------------------  a~x2, b~(y2 -> x2)  ---------
s k k ::                                      a -> a
```

(you can see the type you asked about, `s k :: (a->b)->a->a`, there). Here you can see the type unifications done "step by step" but the two unifications could well have been done together,

```
s     :: (a -> b -> c) -> (a ->     b    ) -> a -> c
  k   ::  x -> y -> x
    k ::                   x2 -> y2 -> x2
-------  a~x, b~y, c~x  => c~x~a  -------------------
----------------------  a~x2, b~(y2 -> x2)  ---------
s k k ::                                      a -> a
```

The end result is of course the same. Whether we read the above  diagram at once or in stages, it's the same diagram. Currying is nice, and it *works*. And since it *works*, when you've already applied a *thing* to *two* other things you needn't concern yourself with the partial application in stages. Except maybe as a mental exercise.

There's nothing much to say about all these interim types really. You just write them one under the other, being careful to rename the variables consistently at different invocations to avoid capture, noting the resulting equivalences and using them to simplify the resulting types.

Last thing to notice is that `s k s` and `s k (s k)` etc. could also be used for the same purpose. *Almost*, just like `($)` is *almost* the same as `id`.